# Send Email To Admin

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, smtp, automapper

I need to send a lot of different forms to the mail. For example `FeedBackForm` `ContactsForm`. the only difference is that I create different `mail.Subject` and `mail.Body`.

I need to automate this action.

```
public class EmailService : IEmailService, ITransientService
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public EmailService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task SendFormToAdminEmailAsync (FeedBackForm form)
    {
        var fromAddress = _configuration["EmailCredentials:Email"];
        var fromPassword = _configuration["EmailCredentials:Password"];

        var toAddress = new MailAddress("someAdminGmail@gmail.com");

        var mail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(fromAddress), toAddress);

        mail.Subject = $"Need consultation {form.Name}";
        mail.Body = $@"Name:  {form.Name}
                       Email: {form.Email}
                       Phone: {form.PhoneNumber}
                       Link:  {form.BotLink}";

        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
        {
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someAdminGmail@gmail.com", fromPassword);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;

            await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this, in this method I accepted a generic type, and with the help of automapper I mapped what I needed, and specified the conditions in MappingConfig, but I don’t know if this is correct

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'd proceed would be to (if you don't already have it) create an interface for forms (`FeedbackForm`, `ContactForm`)

```
interface IFormData
{
    // Don't know if you have some common ground on forms
    // This may be an empty interface to mark types that can be worked with
    // in later stages of this solution.
}
```

You can create an interface like:

```
interface IMailHydrator
{
    void Hydrate(MailMessage message, IFormData form);
}
```

And than you create implementation like

```
class FeedBackFormHydrator : IMailHydrator
{
    public void Hydrate(MailMessage message, IFormData form)
    {
        var cast = form as FeedBackForm;
        if (cast == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        message.Subject = $"Need consultation {cast.Name}";
        mail.Body = $@"Name:  {cast.Name}
                       Email: {cast.Email}
                       Phone: {cast.PhoneNumber}
                       Link:  {cast.BotLink}";
    }
}
```

You register those hydrators in your DI as named/keyed registrations where the name/key is full name of form type. So something like:

```
this.AddSingleton<IMailHydrator, FeedBackFormHydrator>().Named(typeof(FeedBackForm).FullName);
```

You change your method to:

```
public async Task SendFormToAdminEmailAsync (IFormData form)
{
    var fromAddress = _configuration["EmailCredentials:Email"];
    var fromPassword = _configuration["EmailCredentials:Password"];
    var toAddress = new MailAddress("someAdminGmail@gmail.com");
    var mail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(fromAddress), toAddress);

    var hydrator = this.container.Resolve<IMailHydrator>(form.GetType().FullName);
    hydrator.Hydrate(mail, form);
    using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
    {
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someAdminGmail@gmail.com", fromPassword);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
    }
}
```

There may be some tweaking depending on your DI container.